# Passing a parent component value as param in child component

Tags: angular, decorator

I am sending a string `name` from the parent component to the child component via the `@Input` decorator. This string `name` is then fed into a function in the child component as a parameter.

So every time an event (a click for example) in the parent component is fired, it causes this `name` value to change and which in turn affects the function in the child component (since it takes `name` as a param). This is a snippet from my child component:

```
@Input() name: string;

ngOnChanges() {
  this.childFunction(this.name);
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is that the child view keeps the value from the previous function call. With every subsequent click in parent, it just adds the new output, when I want it to remove the old one and replace the new one with it.

UPDATE: I have found a solution but I'm not sure if its the right one. Basically since the child function returns an array of objects, I am simply emptying out the array at the beginning of every function call. This seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngOnInit only ever runs one time for a component. Use ngOnChanges instead. See the docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges

> Angular calls its ngOnChanges() method whenever it detects changes to
>   input properties of the component (or directive). This example
>   monitors the OnChanges hook.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    let chng = changes[propName];
    let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
    let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
    this.changeLog.push(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I seem to have struck one further problem. I've updated the original post explaining it. Please have a look if you can.

Comment: Subsequent problems should be in a different question